# Wann benutzt man "ob" und wann benutzt man "wenn"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, difference, sentence-structure

Ich habe drei Jahre Deutsch studiert. Ich habe natürlich "wenn" benutzt, aber ich habe nie "ob" benutzt. Ich weiß, dass beide auf Englisch "if" bedeuten. Ich habe "wenn" sehr oft gehört, "ob" jedoch nicht.

Hier sind meine Fragen:

1. Wann benutzt man "ob" und wann benutzt man "wenn"?
2. Was ist der grammatische Unterschied zwischen den beiden Wörtern?
3. Wohin kommt das Verb, wenn man "ob" benutzt?

Comment: Grobe Merkregel: Wenn man "whether" statt "if" sagen kann, dann ist die deutsche Übersetzung "ob".

Comment: You also use "ob" in questions with yes/no answer. For instance: "Do you know if he will come - I don't know if he will come" (Weißt du, ob er kommt - Nein, ich weiß nicht, ob er kommt"

Comment: The verb is put at the end of the sentence.

Comment: "Ich kann nicht sagen, ob ich heute zur Party **komme**" - "Kachelmann weiß nicht, ob es morgen **regnet**" - "Ich weiß nicht, ob wir Hausaufgaben **bekommen haben**" - "Ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob die Menschheit jemals ans Ende des Universums **gelangt**"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(trotz community wiki als eigene Antwort, weil ich nicht deutsch und englisch in der Antwort mischen wollte)*

### Zu Frage 2:

**Grammatisch** gibt es nur einen geringen Unterschied. Beide Worte sind Konjunktionen<sup>[[Wikipedia]](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konjunktion_%28Wortart%29)</sup><sup>[canoo]</sup> (bzw. Subjunktoren<sup>[[IDS - Grammis]](http://hypermedia.ids-mannheim.de/call/public/sysgram.ansicht?v_typ=d&v_id=384)</sup>), aber mit unterschiedlicher Bedeutung<sup>[canoo]</sup>:

- „ob“ hat keine eindeutige Bedeutung, es ordnet lediglich unter, leitet also einen untergeordneten Nebensatz (Konjunktionalsatz) ein. Häufig steht der mit "ob" eingeleitete Nebensatz nach einer Frage, nach einem Ausdruck des Zweifeln oder der Unsicherheit<sup>[canoo]</sup>.
- „wenn“ hingegen gehört zu den [konditionalen](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Konjunktion/Bedeutung/konditional.html) / [temporalen](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Konjunktion/Bedeutung/temporal.html) Konjuntionen,

### Zu Frage 3:

Der von „ob“ eingeleitete Konjunktionalsatz<sup>[canoo]</sup> ist ein Nebensatz<sup>[[Wikipedia]](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nebensatz)</sup>, bei dem — gemäß dem Regelfall für Nebensätze — das finite Verb am Satzende steht. Das gilt, soviel ich sehe, bei „ob“ ohne Ausnahme.

Comment: Danke für deine antwort, die hilfe mir sehr viel!

Answer (score 6):

1. - If you can replace the "**if**" with "**when**": **wenn**
   - If you can replace the "**if**" with "**whether**": **ob**
2. "Wenn" is an **implication** whereas "ob" is not.

   - Wenn es regnet, wird die Straße nass.

     i.e. If it rains, the street **will** get wet.
   - Ob wir heute noch ankommen ist eine Frage der Zeit.

     i.e. It's a matter of time, if we **will (or will not)** arrive today.
3. ?? (Feel free to edit)

Comment: Note that in English you usually _cannot_ replace "if" with "then" -- the former refers to a condition, the later to a point in tame. Treating them as interchangable is a typical mistake native German speakers make.

Answer (score 3):

Most questions start with a question word (wer, wie was , wann etc. ). The only questions that don't are the yes-no question.

> Hast du einen Euro?

Now asking directly is not the only moment, questions are raised. We say questions all the time in indirect form... like

> I don't know when the Bus goes.
>
> I can't remember where my keys are.
>
> Tell me how old you are.

The question words serves as a subordinating conjunction here.
The direct yes/no-question has no question word. However a conjunction of some kind is needed for indirect speech as the 2 sentences have to be joined and coordinated. This job is done by **if/whether** in English. In German this is done by **ob**.

**Wenn** has nothing to do with this. **Wenn** introduces temporal or conditional informations that specify **when/under which circumstances** something will/would/would have happened.

Mixing up the 2 is really confusing. It might still make sense but with a totally different meaning.

> Sag mir, ob du kommst.
> Sag mir, wenn du kommst.

The first sentence requests an answer in either case (I'll come/I won't come). The second request an answer only if it is positive.

On a side note **ob** can also be used as a preposition in sense of "because of"

> Ob des starken Regens blieben wir zuhause.
> Because of the strong rain, we stayed home.

If you want to read up more detailed on [ob](http://yourdailygerman.wordpress.com/2012/03/05/meaning-of-ob/) and [wenn](http://yourdailygerman.wordpress.com/2012/03/30/meaning-wenn/) those are the links to my blog... I have written quite elaborate articles on both words.

Answer (score 0):

"ob" is used in connection with a question or something you want to know (mostly in indirect speech):

> Er fragt, ob der Briefträger schon gekommen ist.
>
> Ich möchte wissen, ob es morgen wärmer wird.

After "wenn" comes a possibility or a condition:

> Wenn der Briefträger schon gekommen ist, werde ich die Post holen.
>
> Wenn ich den Schalter betätige, geht das Licht an.